# Ground truth map for a gazebo world like the willowgarage model

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I use the turtlebot in the willowgarage world to create a semantic mapping system. As the actual mapping (using gmapping for example) is not the most important part of this effort, I would like to be able to use ground truths for the start as well. I found a way to get the ground truth pose (using the topic /gazebo/model_states), but now I also want a way to get the ground truth map, or at least some way to construct such a map. Is that possible?

Alternatively, is there a way to provide gmapping with the ground truth pose such that it just builds perfect maps (assuming a static world)?

Ultimately I would like to have a tf frame /mobile_base_groudntruth and a map topic /map_groundtruth.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Best,
Koen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5760/ground-truth-map-for-a-gazebo-world-like-the-willowgarage-model/) by [koenlek](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/712/koenlek/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can also use [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=custom_messages) to generate a 2d image of the Willow Garage floorplan.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [koenlek](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/712/koenlek/) on 2014-06-06**:
I build a tool for ROS that can generate maps, based on your link. It can be found here for anybody who is interested:

`https://github.com/koenlek/ros_semantic_turtle`

Package: `st_gazebo_perfect_map_generator`

**Comment by [Eric](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2575/eric/) on 2016-04-28**:
The repo above no longer contains this package - it was last seen in this commit: https://github.com/koenlek/ros_lemtomap/tree/154c782cf8feb9112bc928e33a59728ca2192489/st_gazebo_perfect_map_generator

**Comment by [Eric](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2575/eric/) on 2016-04-28**:
The link in the post is also now dead, and should be http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=custom_messages

**Comment by [simff](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3843/simff/) on 2018-01-06**:
I also need a ground truth for my map, is this generator package still somewhere available?

**Comment by [shaihi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3727/shaihi/) on 2018-02-07**:
All links are now dead - both in answer and in comments...
Must admit that the answers experience of Gazebo is very bad...

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-02-07**:
There's a bug in Askbot which adds some garbage to the end of the link, you should be able to copy it and paste on your browser. All the links are working for me like this.

**Comment by [shaihi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3727/shaihi/) on 2018-02-08**:
Thanks! Works well with copy&paste.

**Comment by [hyfan1116](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7259/hyfan1116/) on 2018-11-14**:
Recreated the package (Kinetic) in case someone needs it: https://github.com/hyfan1116/pgm_map_creator

**Comment by [tsdk00](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/10659/tsdk00/) on 2019-05-05**:
Does it work only on Gazebo 9, since it throws an error on Gazebo 7 while doing catkin_make?